# System.cmd avoid pushing to logs

Tags: elixir

I'm running a bash command in Ubuntu via [System.cmd](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/System.html#cmd/3):

```
System.cmd("ffmpeg", ["-i", video_path, "-ss", thumbnail_time, "-vframes", "1", "-f", "image2", temp_path])
```

Unfortunately, system output is so heavy so I don't want to see it, especially in my tests. How can I make `System.cmd` doesn't appear in my logs?

Comment: Does `ffmpeg` print something to stderr? If so, try `System.cmd("ffmpeg", ["-i", video_path, "-ss", thumbnail_time, "-vframes", "1", "-f", "image2", temp_path], stderr_to_stdout: true)`.

Comment: No, it doesn't put errors

Comment: Are you printing the output of `System.cmd` somewhere then? (Could you give `stderr_to_stdout: true` a try anyways?)

Comment: @Dogbert crap, `stderr_to_stdout` works! Could you create an answer with this info, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting output from `ffmpeg` in your terminal even though `System.cmd/3` is supposed to return the output of the command as a binary is that by default `System.cmd/3` does not capture stderr output.

One way to fix this is to ask `System.cmd/3` to capture stderr too. You can do that by passing `stderr_to_stdout: true` as the third argument:

```
System.cmd("ffmpeg"‌​, ["-i", video_path, "-ss", thumbnail_time, "-vframes", "1", "-f", "image2", temp_path], stderr_to_stdout: true)
```

Another way is to lower the log level of `ffmpeg` so that it doesn't log as many things as it does by default. You can do this by adding 2 parameters to the start: `"-loglevel"` and one of `"quiet"`,  `"panic"`, or any other log level you want. `"quiet"` will send absolutely no output to stderr, even if the command doesn't run successfully. These are documented in the [ffmpeg's `man` page](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/ae0192ef5fe8ca67b6532a57f829f744db3facb9/doc/fftools-common-opts.texi#L165-L196).

Answer (score 0):

To capture (and not show) output in tests use [ExUnit.CaptureIO](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/ex_unit/ExUnit.CaptureIO.html).

To demonstrate, let's first execute a `System.cmd` without capturing IO:

```
iex(1)> hostfun = fn -> System.cmd("hostname", [], into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line)) end
#Function<20.52032458/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(2)> hostfun.()
dedalus.local
{%IO.Stream{device: :standard_io, line_or_bytes: :line, raw: false}, 0}
iex(3)>
```

See how the host name "dedalus.local" was written to the console? That's what we want to avoid, right?

Next, let's execute the same command, but this time capturing IO:

```
iex(3)> import ExUnit.Assertions
ExUnit.Assertions
iex(4)> import ExUnit.CaptureIO
ExUnit.CaptureIO
iex(5)> assert(capture_io(hostfun) == "dedalus.local\n")
true
iex(6)>
```

We run the same `hostfun`, but this time its `System.cmd` output does not go to the screen. Instead it is captured, and we're able to `assert` its value was "dedalus.local\n".

To understand the magic:
When evaluating the `hostfun` the `capture_io` replaces the `group_leader`. In Erlang/Elixir...

> every process is a member of some process group and all groups have a group leader. All I/O from the group is channeled to the group leader. When a new process is spawned, it gets the same group leader as the spawning process.
>
> (from http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#group_leader-0)

Note: if your ffmpeg command writes to `stderr` you can capture that as well.

Hope this helps!